# Error r6002 floating point support not loaded?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am working in visual studio 2010 in windows 8. At some point of my program while trying to read numbers as float from  a file I am getting error r6002 floating point support not loaded.
I couldnt find a way to solve it. Please help.
Here is the code

```
while(fgets((char *)pucLine, 512, fp[i]) != NULL)
{
    float fvals[8] ;                
    int res ;               
    res = sscanf_s((char *)pucTmp, "%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f",
            &fvals[0],&fvals[1],&fvals[2])&fvals[3],&fvals[4],&fvals[5],  &fvals[6],&fvals[7]);
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message?

Comment: @NPE the whole day i was trying this

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: I suspect this is not the case however make sure you are not using .dlls from some other version of Visual Studio. One possible reason for this is a CRT mismatch.

Comment: `&fvals[2])&fvals[3]` I assume this is was copied wrong?

Comment: Please remove the file input from the example. Please reduce the example to a single float parsing operation. Any changes resulting from these adjustments?